# not declared in scope, beginners snail racing game

Tags: c++

Ok, I googled and found some answers here on this site regarding this, but the answers are too different for me to really do anything with them, so I ask again and hope for the best.

I got the following errors in g++;

```
snailrace.cpp: In function ‘int race(int, int)’:

snailrace.cpp:101:21: error: ‘rand’ was not declared in this scope


snailrace.cpp:123:3: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before ‘{’ token


snailrace.cpp:128:3: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input
```

I think I will be able to solve everything except the `snailrace.cpp:101:21: error: ‘rand’ was not declared in this scope` I tried EVERYTHING and it wont help! 
How do I solve that!? It is driving me insane. 
Thanks!

```
//The snail race.

#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

//Function declaration.
int race(int,int); 
void race(void);
int menu(void);
int placebet(int);
void init(void);

//Variables 
int money = 200; 

//the main function
int main(void)
{
  using std::cout; 

  init();
  int user_respons;

  cout << "Welcome to the snail race!\n"; 

  while(user_respons = menu())
  {

    switch(user_respons)
    {
      case 1:
      case 2:
      case 3: 
    ::money +=
    race(placebet(user_respons), user_respons); 
    break;

      case 4: //The user did not bet
    race();
    break; 
  }
}
return 0; 

}

//Display user menu and sends user selection to the main function
int menu( void )
{
  using std::cout;
  using std::cin; 

  int user_respons;

  cout << "You have " << money << " USD.\n";

  do
  {
    cout << "Race Menu: \n\n"
     << "1) Bet on snail 1\n"
     << "2) Bet on snail 2\n"
     << "3) Bet on snail 3\n"
     << "4) Do not bet, just watching"
     << "0) Leave the race"; 

    cin >> user_respons;
  }
  while(user_respons < 0 && user_respons > 4);
  return user_respons;
}

//Decide how much one person will bet on a snail.

int placebet(int user_respons)

{
  using std::cout;
  using std::cin;

  int bet_amount;

  cout << "Snail " << user_respons << " is a good choice!\n";
  cout << "How much would you like to bet on your snail?\n"; 
  cin >> bet_amount; 
  return bet_amount;
}

//if just watching the race
void race(void) 
{
  race(0, 0); 
}

//if they are betting money. 
int race(int money, int user_respons)
{
  using std::cout; 
  using std::cin; 

  //Stores random number
  int winner = rand() % 3 + 1; 

  cout << "And the snails are off!\n"; 
  cout << "Look at them go! \n"; 
  cout << "The winner snail is " << winner << "\n"; 

  if(winner == user_respons)
  {
    cout << "You win!\n";

    return money * 2; 
  }
  else 
  {
  cout << "You lost.\n"; 

  return money / 2;
  }


  //Handles the program start random
  void init(void) 
  {
    using std::srand; 
    using std::time; 

    srand(time(0)); 
  }
```

Comment: is this homework? If so, add a tag..

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes nice salt

Comment: The incredible part is that the snails finish the race in the amount of cpu cycles it takes to write 2 `const char *` to std out.

Comment: No its not homework, I am doing this in my own free time.

Comment: You should avoid declarations like `int menu(void);`. It is a C++ code, so the `void` type in a parameterless function is not justified. `int menu();` is more than enough. For more information about that "abomination", see: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/newbie.html#faq-29.4

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`rand` is part of `cstdlib` which you did not include. Add

```
#include <cstdlib>
```

Comment: Thanks! the #include <cstdlib> was the problem, you see I knew that and still I missed it....!

Comment: No problem, good luck on your snail race, maybe consider sleeping the thread randomly for a real snail race!

Comment: Huh, I always thought `rand()` was in `<ctime>` for some reason.  Google says: "rand ctime": 3,810,000 results, "rand cstdlib":  91,200 results.

Comment: @MooingDuck "Mooing Duck" returns over 15 million results maybe its in that header :)

Comment: @Joe: You forgot to include `rand`.  "rand mooingduck" returns 109 results.  The first seven are me on this site :D

Answer (score 3):

You forgot a brace before `void init(void)`.

```
int race(int money, int user_respons)
{
    /* ... */
    else 
    {
        cout << "You lost.\n"; 
        return money / 2;
    }    
} /* <---- missing */


//Handles the program start random
void init(void) 
{
    using std::srand; 
    using std::time; 

    srand(time(0)); 
}
```

This likely happened because of the inconsistent indentation.

Answer (score 2):

For the first error, you need to `#include <stdlib.h>` (it's required for [rand](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/rand/))

Answer (score 2):

If you are coding using gcc then you have to include

```
    #include<cstdlib>
```